# How to fix exit code issue while using WinSCP for SFTP from within SSIS package?

Tags: ssis, winscp

I am using SSIS 2005 to do some SFTPtasks using `WinSCP`. I googled about the error  but couldn't make it work. I got this error:

> [Execute Process Task] Error: In Executing "C:\Program Files\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" "-script=C:\Documents and Settings\nian_z\Desktop\temp\SSISMovingSOA\removeSOA8.txt" at "C:\Program Files\WinSCP", The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".

Here is my WinSCP script that I use:

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
#open sftp://user:password@server:22
#cd /m/vo/Cont/fileftp
get OrderOutbound*
close
exit
```

For above script, I even tried leaving only one statement at a time, but still got error.

Here is the setup of the execute process task.

[image: Execute Process Task]

Comment: Does it retrieve the expected files? If so, it may be the case that you need to change the `SuccessValue` property to 1

Comment: Physician, [heal thyself](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_exit_code)

Comment: @billinkc, no it retrieved nothing. I just set it up in ssis and run it in ssis 2005 and got the error.

Comment: @siva I am new to winscp. How can I run it in cmd?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is **not** an answer but an attempt to help you find a solution to your problem.

#### Try this:

Try the following steps to find out if your script is actually working outside of SSIS or not.

- Click **`Windows Start`** and click **`Run...`**
- Type **`cmd`** to open *Command Prompt*.
- On the command prompt window, type the following command at the prompt to switch to the WinSCP installation directory. I have the WinSCP installed in the following directory. Change the path according to your environment settings.

> cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP"

- If your WinSCP script file `removeSOA8.txt` is located in the path `C:\Documents and Settings\userid\Desktop\temp\SSISMovingSOA\` with spaces, then type the following command by enclosing the script path in double quotes to run the script and also use the **`/log`** option to capture all the status messages.

> WinSCP.exe "/script=C:\Documents and Settings\userid\Desktop\temp\SSISMovingSOA\removeSOA8.txt" /log=C:\temp\WinSCP_log.txt

After the script executes, your will find that a log file named **`WinSCP_log.txt`** will be created in the path **`C:\temp`**. Read through the file to identify if there are any error messages.

#### Attempt to run FTP in SSIS:

I tried downloading a file from FTP using WinSCP with the following script:

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open ftp://myuserid:mypassword@ftp.myftpsite.com:21 -passive=on
cd /root/somefolder/
option transfer binary
get SomeFileOnFTP.txt c:\temp\
close
exit
```

Here are the settings how I have configured the `Execute Process Task` within the SSIS package.

[image: Execute Process Task]

The process ran successfully in BIDS.

[image: Execution]

Hope that gives you an idea.

Comment: All right, I got it work. It turned out I should put the whole "/script=C:\Documents and Settings\userid\Desktop\temp\SSISMovingSOA\removeSOA8.txt" in the Argument field of the execute process task.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the script from SQL Server job agent then mostly you will get this exit error.

Scenario: In my case I faced when i m trying to download a file from sFTP server.

**Solution :**

**Step 1 - Create a batch file**
@echo off

CD "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP"

winscp.com **/ini=nul** /script=C:\path\download_script_pm.txt

Exit

*Note: When calling using SQL Server Job agent make sure to NULL out the “ini” configuration else it will throw up this error*

**Step2 – create a txt file (winscp script)**

option echo on

option batch on

option confirm off

open sftp://user:password@sftp.xxxx.com/ -hostkey="ssh-edXXXX-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx"

option confirm off

get -filemask="*>=1D" /sftp_Path/File_Name_*.csv 
 C:\local_path_for_downloaded_file\"

exit

Note: make sure to use hostkey. To obtain host key you need to do the following : 
1.  Open winscp app tool and login to the server

2. Click Session -> Generate Session / URL code option
3. Check SSH Host key and copy the finger print value and use in the winscp hostkey value

Answer (score -1):

Earlier I was getting the same error but now is working fine for me.

**SSIS Execute Process Task :**

Executable - C:\SSIS\SSIS_2008_Projects\HRIS_RepomanFusion_Load\WinSCP\WinSCP.com

Arguments  - "/script=wscpBatchTest.txt" /log=C:\SSIS\SSIS_2008_Projects\FTP_Load\WinSCP\WinSCP_log.txt

Working Directory - C:\SSIS\SSIS_2008_Projects\HRIS_RepomanFusion_Load\WinSCP

[image]

Here is the WinSCP script that I use: **wscpBatchTest.txt**

```
option batch
option confirm off
open sftp://username:password@ftp.test.com
option transfer binary
cd /home/SAFAA
get employeedetails.csv C:\SSIS\SSIS_2008_Projects\SAFAA\InputDirectory\
close
exit
```

Comment: You didn't really explain what did you change to fix the problem.